# Compare data in two separate sheets in Excel and only pull out the common data that satisfies a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets on Excel.

One is a list of genes and it has 809R x 23Columns. The columns I am interested in from this sheet is Col1, which has the name of the gene.

The second sheet has 2078R x 11C. The 2nd column has the name of the gene and the 4th column has the HI score.

I want to compare these two sheets and pull out any gene which has a HI score = 3. I am unsure how to do this so far on Excel. I tried this, MATCH(B2,Sheet1! B2:B6,0)which has failed. Please could someone help

Some data to work with: Sheet 2
[image]

Sheet 1
[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the FILTER function?

Comment: Yes it does! I filtered to HI=3 and tried the formula but it didn't work

Comment: I assume you need `XLOOKUP()` here, `FILTER()` will not expand with the same size of the other sheet range and will output only those have `HI=3`, but if you use `XLOOKUP()` it will return `#N/A` for those not matching. That said it could be `=XLOOKUP(1,(B2=Sheet1! B$2:B$6)*(--LEFT(Sheet1!D$2:D$6)=3),Sheet1! B$2:B$6,NA())` . Not attempted there is no sample data posted as markdown table, it takes time to transform images to excel because sometimes it doesnt convert correctly.

Comment: It's difficult to check any possible solutions with the screen shots shown - there is too much data and I can't see any matches between the first and second sheets. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which applies to data as well as code. Please provide any sample data as text in markdown form which can be copied e.g. using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: The name of the gene is "R", or do you really mean within sheet 1? which one?

Comment: @TomSharpe well put indeed. thank you.

Comment: a) Include column and row labels so that you can refer to each in a clear/understandable way; (e.g. I don't know if 4th column allows for 1st col with 'Rs' in it, a lot of second-guessing on my part which is why no-one has attempted to solve, or at least one of the reasons)
b) No proper sample data mate! I'm not replicating what you have written here, rather filter down on one of the gene types that match in each sheet, and then provide this in a user friendly way (you could just as easily make up an example in markdown with gene name "A" for instance, and apply the filter function)
c) tbc

Comment: c) ..from pvs... your attempt at matching - I suspect you know why this clearly wouldn't achieve the objective - at best you would only get a number corresponding to which row the corresponding gene matched upon; there is no reference to the column with scores - clearly you need to do some text manipulation to get a score of 3 out of that... I'll attempt a solution below using some assumptions on what I think you're after... but I'm going out on a limb here given the issues with this unclear Q that requires those attempting to assist to 'think-a-lot' to process this info....

Comment: d) ..."I want to compare these two sheets and pull out anything with a score of 3".... is unclear - what exactly do you want to do? Are the lists in either sheet unique wrt gene name? If not,  how exactly would you like to reflect this in Sheet 2? i.e. where is the function you want to include going to sit,. how to treat duplicate rows from sheet 1 (where more than 1 has the same gene name you're looking up from Sheet 2)... and which fields do you want to bring back (just the hi score - obviously it would be 3 if you're only  looking up this value (assuming the match existed)...?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9iN4AxihtC45qlb2LvQ?e=ILjzoM)/screenshots refer:

**(A) Index/match (1st match if duplicates in Table 2)**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(K4:K8,MATCH(B4:B11&D1&"*",I4:I8&J4:J8,0)),"-")
```

[image: Scenario A]

---

**(B): ByRow / Filter / Textjoin (Table 2 duplicates, text retrieved)**

```
=BYROW(B4:B11&D1&"*",LAMBDA(a_,TEXTJOIN(",",1,IFERROR(FILTER(K5:K8,--ISNUMBER(MATCH(a_,I5:I8&J5:J8,0))),"-"))))
```

[image: Scenario B]

*Notes: this precise configuration fails if the respective gene in Table 2 has a score ranging 30-39, 300-399, etc. (only 1st digit {3} is checked).  If scores can be larger than 9, then see the '`NOT(ISNUMBER((b2_<=9)*(b2_>=0))`' filtration I apply for scenario C to circumvent/address, where b2_ defined as 2nd char (numeric/otherwise) for 'Score' field in Table 2.*

---

**(C) ByRow, Average of interest_2 (duplicates, value retrieved/summarized)**

```
=LET(
b0_,$J$4:$J$8,
b1_,--LEFT(b0_,1),
b2_,--MID(b0_,2,1),
z_,BYROW($B$4:$B$11,LAMBDA(a_,LET(
a1_,(b1_=$D$1)*NOT(ISNUMBER((b2_<=9)*(b2_>=0)))*($I$4:$I$8=a_),
a2_,IFERROR(SUM($L$4:$L$8*a1_)/SUM(--a1_),"-"),
a2_))),
z_)
```

[image: Scenario C]

*Notes: if you don't mind a 'helper' column in Table 2, extract the score from 'Score' field in that table (put in col M for instance), and you can simply use '`averageifs`' function to retrieve avg. value from Table 2 in Table 1 for respective Gene names.*

---